# Creating entire DOM object with inline styles using innerHTML, is that safe?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I have two options:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.style.cssText = 'background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #000000; ' +
    'opacity: 0.7; display: block; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; ' +
    'right: 0; position: fixed; zIndex: ' + zIndexHighest() + ';';
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

Or

```
var span = document.createElement('span');
span.innerHTML = '<div style="background: none repeat scroll 0px 0px #000000; ' +
    'opacity: 0.7; display: block; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; left: 0px; ' +
    'right: 0px; position: fixed; z-index: ' + zIndexHighest() + ';"></div>';
document.body.appendChild(span);
```

Obviously the second way is faster but I remember reading somewhere that innerHTML may ignore inline css styling. Does anyone know if this is true?

My reason for wanting to do this the second way is because I want to put a couple of divs into the dom (I want to create a small custom modal dialog)

Comment: A `div` in a `span` (this is not valid HTML, to be very correct)? Your second code piece is missing something... You are appending `div` but you are not defining it.

Comment: changed it to make sense

Comment: The first seems semantically neater, which isn't an argument one way or the other unless you (a) think neatness is important, and (b) agree with my subjective feeling about which is neater.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is safe to use with innerHTML, but why not use a CSS class instead of inline styling? It will make your code much simpler and easier to read, as well as use less bandwith and shrink your file size. The only time I ever use inline styling is to declare the width or height of an object, and maybe one more thing.